# dll "drop in" architecture using Castle Windsor & MicroKernel

Tags: c#, plugins, inversion-of-control, castle-windsor, microkernel

I'd like to create a framework that uses IoC without needing any configuration:

So instead of (adjusted from http://www.castleproject.org/container/gettingstarted/part1/code.html):

```
IWindsorContainer container = new WindsorContainer();
container.AddComponent("someinterface", typeof(ISomeInterface));
ISomeInterface component = (ISomeInterface) container[typeof(ISomeInterface)];
component.DoIt();
container.Release(component);
```

The `container.AddComponent` method would not need to be called, as there would have been some initial step that did some 'auto wiring' by looking in a known directory for any dlls containing classes that implemented ISomeComponent and registered them with the WindsorContainer.

I can see that this would be possible to do from scratch, but ideally I'd like not to rewrite this code if there is an open source project out there that has already done it!

Comment: Why do you want this? What's wrong with using the configuration file? This technique will be hard to maintain IMO.

Comment: Surely it is easier to maintain, as you don't have to keep your config files up to date.

Comment: I wanted to do something similar once upon a time, did you end up rolling your own or did you find something out-of-the-box?

Comment: It was just a toy project I was working on, so in the end I just did it all manually by reflection, i.e. without Windsor. If you are interested I can probably dig out the code and post it here as an answer. I wouldn't use it though, as I think there are issues with it, e.g. interface versioning.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, sounds like you ended up in about the same place I did :)